# I have written a max_heapify code but it is not providing the required result

Tags: c++, heap, max-heap

I took heap size as 14 as it is the initial size of the array, I was doing question 6.2-1 from introduction to algorithms clrs. I did not some other helper function like swap or 'to print array'

I am not very clear on heap size

```
void max_heapify(int arr[],int i){
    int largest ;
    int n = 14;
    int left = 2*i;
    int right = (2*i) + 1;

    if (left <= n && arr[left] > arr[i])
    {
        largest = left;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = i;
    }

    if (right <= n && arr[right] > arr[i])
    {
        largest = right;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = i;
    }

    if(largest != i)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);
        max_heapify(arr, largest);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 27,17,3,16,13,10,1,5,7,12,4,8,9,0 };
    max_heapify(arr, 3);
}
```

Comment: Having a hardcoded size 14 is already suspect. But this is clearly homework, so that probably explains why you are not using real C++. In the real world, you'd use `std::vector<>` and its `.size()`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You should revise the heapify algorithm. What if arr[i] < arr[right] < arr[left] ? Then largest should equal left. But in your case, largest would equal right. Also, right <= n should be right < = n (same goes for left <= n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your checking of the `right` node. You have this:

```
if (left <= n && arr[left] > arr[i])
{
    largest = left;
}
else
{
    largest = i;
}
```

So at this point, `largest` is the larger of `arr[i]` and `arr[left]`. But then you have:

```
if (right <= n && arr[right] > arr[i])
{
    largest = right;
}
else
{
    largest = i;
}
```

This totally negates the work you did above. When you finish executing this code, `largest` will either be equal to `right` or to `i`. It can *never* be equal to `left`.

You need to pick the index of the largest of those three items: `arr[i]`, `arr[left]`, or `arr[right]`.

You can fix your code by replacing the `right` check with this:

```
if (right <= n && arr[right] > arr[largest])
{
    largest = right;
}
```